# SQL Server - getting duplicate rows with different queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get a count of child records (addresses) for each customer. I have 2 queries and I'm wondering if they're the same:

```
SELECT 
    a.AddressId,  c.CustomerID, COUNT(*) AS NumDuplicates 
FROM 
    Customers C
INNER JOIN 
    Addresses a ON c.AddressID = a.AddressID 
GROUP BY 
    c.CustomerID, a.AddressId 
ORDER BY 
    NumDuplicates DESC


SELECT 
    c.CustomerID,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM Addresses a 
     WHERE a.AddressID = c.AddressID) AS AddressCount
FROM 
    Customers c 
ORDER BY 
    AddressCount desc
```

If they're not, what's the difference? If they are which is more efficient?

Comment: That's an easy test for you to do. for the first question, simply compare the results of the queries. for the second one, run them in ssms but first click the 'Include actual execution plan' button. this will add a tab for the execution plan in your results panel, allowing you to compare the efficiency of the 2 queries easily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two queries are different, because the first only returns customers that have at least one match in the address table.  The second returns all customers, even those with no match and having `AddressId` is NULL.

The equivalent first query is:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, COUNT(a.AddressId) AS NumDuplicates
FROM Customers C LEFT JOIN
     Addresses a
     ON c.AddressID = a.AddressID 
GROUP BY c.CustomerID
ORDER BY NumDuplicates DESC;
```

As for performance, you should try them out.  There are reasons why either might be faster.  The second avoids having to do aggregation, but does have a correlated subquery.  However, SQL Server has some tricks for speeding joins and aggregation.  I would guess that the correlated subquery version is faster, but I might be wrong for your data and server.

Comment: Is there a difference between putting the '*' in the count or 'a.AddressId'?

Comment: yes. note that in Gordon's answer the join is a left join, not an inner join. if you use the * in the count, it will return 1 for customers that have no addresses, but if you use AddressId it will return 0, since count ignores null values.

Comment: @Eitan, yes. `COUNT(*)` returns the number of rows in the group.  `COUNT(a.AddressId)` returns the number of rows for which `a.AddressId` is not `NULL`.  In this particular case, `a.AddressId` will be non-null for exactly those rows where a Customer was joined to an Address.  Customers with no address are represented in the results because an outer join is used instead of an inner join.